# LinqDataSource class example

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, linqdatasource

Just starting to look into using LinqDataSource for a GridView and I’m looking for a few more examples on how to set up my data source.

I am hoping later on to use it against a SharePoint List but for now I’m simply after some detailed examples for a class that I can retrieve data from and update.

Here is an example class from MS. I just after more than one example so i have better idea how this work.

A Simple example that is known to work and is a little more complicated would be great

```
public class MovieLibrary
{
        string[] _availableGenres = { "Comedy", "Drama", "Romance" };

        public MovieLibrary()
        {
        }

        public string[] AvailableGenres
        {
            get
            {
                return _availableGenres;
            }
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you looking for a purely in-memory (linq-to-objects) example or something with file and/or database persistence?

Comment: Just in memory example is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using LinqDataSource with SPGridView here is my code.

```
      <SharePoint:SPGridView runat="server" ID="spgvUserTrainingLists" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                DataSourceID="linqDsEmployeeTrainingLists" DataKeyNames="RowId" OnRowDataBound="spgvUserTrainingLists_RowDataBound"
                                AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" AllowFiltering="true" FilteredDataSourcePropertyName="Where"
                                FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat='{1} == "{0}"' FilterDataFields=",TrainingType,,Trainer,Status">
                                <Columns>
                                    <SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Ref #" SortExpression="RefNo" DataField="RefNo" />
                                    <SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="TrainingType" DataField="TrainingType" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Training" SortExpression="TrainingTitle">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlTrainingDetail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrainingTitle") %>'
                                                NavigateUrl="#" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Trainer" SortExpression="Trainer" DataField="Trainer" />
                                    <SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" DataField="Status" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/DELITEM.GIF" runat="server"
                                                UseSubmitBehaviour="false" CommandValue='<%# Eval("RowId") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:DeleteTraining(this);" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    No training yet.
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </SharePoint:SPGridView>
                            <SharePoint:SPGridViewPager ID="SPGridViewPager1" runat="server" GridViewId="spgvUserTrainingLists" />
                            <aspweb:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="linqDsEmployeeTrainingLists" OnSelecting="linqDs_Selecting" />
```

In the LinqDataSource Selecting event is where the data binding happened

```
protected void linqDs_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        object parameter = null;

        if (e.SelectParameters.TryGetValue("employee", out parameter))
        {
            e.Result = DefaultBLL.GetEmployeeTrainingLists(parameter.ToString());
        }
    }


Hope this help.
```

Comment: thank you very much. do you edit any of this data via SPGridView?

Comment: In ASP.NET Gridview you can handle editing via the RowCommand, but with SPGridView I used the SPMenuField to do that. Try googling on how to use SPGridView and SPMenuField